# WebDriver: find elements by text

Tags: webdriver, xpath

I know that WebDriver can locate *links* through their text, using `find_element_by_link_text` or `find_element_by_partial_link_text`.

Is it possible to locate any element (such as `li`, `div`, `span`, ...) by text?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes.  WebDriver supports using an XPath to locate an element by the text it contains.  For example, the following XPath locates any div containing the string "Hello Justin":

```
//div[contains(.,'Hello Justin')]
```

Comment: Thanks, that's great. I'm new to xpath. Do you know if WebDriver supports xpath 2.0?

Comment: According to http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html#commands-and-operation, WebDriver uses whatever XPath support is available in the browser.  In other words, if the browser supports XPath 2.0, WebDriver should too.

Comment: The expression //div[contains() ....  is an invalid expression.

Answer (score 4):

As User246 mentioned, the xpath support depends on the browser.  I have found a few problems with using XPath cross-browser.  My solution for this problem was to find elements by tag name first, then iterate through the list of elements matching the tag and look for the attributes that I want to match on as well.